# Spring boot and javascript node_modules

Tags: maven, spring-boot, build, yarnpkg

I´m currently building a spring-boot application, which also uses some javascript-stuff. I use yarn as a package-manager to manage the different js-libraries.

Now I wonder, how I would include these resources into my spring-boot-project? Simply including the whole node_module-folder as a resource seems to be overhead for me, as this doesn´t neccessarily contain only the required sources (for me it is more like my local maven-repo-path). How do I identify, which java-script-resources should be included in my jar in the end, so that I can also reference them in my Thymeleaf-HTML-templates.

I already found the 'frontend-maven-plugin' (https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) which helps me to install all my yarn-dependencies during build, but it doesn´t care about the build-process, as far as I can see.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider using webpack or some other javascript bundler/task runner to bundle your javascript and required dependencies into a single file. Then you can simply include that bundled file in your jar. For example: http://justincalleja.com/2016/04/17/serving-a-webpack-bundle-in-spring-boot/

Comment: But is there no other way? I already have yarn in place to do all this. Only question would be how to bundle it the right way. Introducing a dependency on another tool will raise complexity again.

Comment: I am quite doubtful that you'll be able to find a java-native tool to  compile/bundle the javascript itself - I'm not sure anyone would care to invest time to build such a thing when there are plenty of javascript native options that could just be exec'd out to